# Trying to open online RPD from BI Administration tool OBIEE 12c

Tags: obiee, oracle-bi

I am using OBIEE 12c which is installed on different server and i am trying to open the deployed repository in online mode from my BI-Administration Client tool but not able to open, I was also configuring BI Server DSN but some error occurred which I am not able to solve.

[Click for the error image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Sh8mJ.png)

I had tried different ports (9514,9500,9503,9502,9505) to configure but didn't worked.
If i am using wrong port then please tell me where to find the right port for this.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

The nQSError: 12017 is specific to a port configuration issue. Either the port is incorrect, or the server/network firewall is blocking it.

As you may know,  **9514** is the default BI system component port; however, it seems as though the BI Server system component port may have been changed since the initial installation.

You can check the BI Server system component (obis1) port in:

Enterprise Manager Fusion Middleware Control (under Target Navigation) -> Business Intelligence -> biinstance -> Availability tab -> Processes sub tab.

Alternatively, you can run the command below on the server to check the ports:
`[Oracle_Home]/user_projects/domains/bin/bi/bitools/bin/status.sh -v`

---

(*My answer above is based on Oracle's internal knowledge article detailing this error (Doc ID 2148653).*)